# Generating bundle.js with webpack & gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, bundle, webpack

I have configured `gulp & webpack` to generate a bundle.js file, take a look the code below:

**Gulp**

```
// Webpack
gulp.task('webpack', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/app.js')
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

**Webpack**

```
var path = require('path');

module.export = {
    entry: './app/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: "./build/bundle.js",
        sourceMapFilename: "./build/bundle.map"
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel',
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve('./app'),
        extenstions: ['', '.js']
    }
}
```

Basically my problem is the file is generated correctly but the file name is wrong, should be `bundle.js` and I'm getting a random file name like `63432692d402c38f8df5.js`

Any idea what is going on?

[image]

Comment: Afaik in Webpack there is `filename` and `path` so not sure `./build/bundle.js` is correct

Comment: The path is correct, I have added an image. @elclanrs

Comment: What I mean is that instead of `filename: ./build/bundle.js` you'd do `filename: 'bundle.js', path: './build'`

Comment: I have tried with output: `{ path: __dirname + "/build", filename: "bundle.js}` and I still getting the same.. is very weird. @elclanrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `module.export` to `module.exports` in your webpack.config.js